# draw lines and text to an image file

Tags: c++, image, graph, ppm

I want to draw lines and text to an image file in c++. I've already considered using the ppm image format, but there I would have to create functions for getting the pixels of a line etc.

I do NOT want any huge game library with ticks or drawing something in windows on the screen.

Is there anything that I could use for that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can give **CImg** a try https://cimg.eu/

It is a header-only library and it can do what you're asking for (plus more, you can also use X11 for plotting if you provide the link dependencies for example)